# ASP.NET web application project ProfileBase.Create(userName) method always returns profile of current user

Tags: asp.net, webforms, sqlmembershipprovider, asp.net-profiles

I am using [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/19/writing-a-custom-asp-net-profile-class.aspx) to implement ASP.NET SQLMembership Profile Provider in my ASP.NET 4.0 Web Application project (NOT website project). I am using Forms authentication. On my admin page I need to display the profile info of all the users. But for some reason, the following code is always returning the profile of the current user instead of each user whose username is provided:

```
ProfileInfoCollection oProfInfoColl = ProfileManager.GetAllProfiles(ProfileAuthenticationOption.All);
string sUserName = "";

foreach (ProfileInfo oPi in oProfInfoColl)
{
    sUserName = oPi.UserName;
    UserProfile oPc = UserProfile.GetUserProfile(sUserName);
    oDataTbl.Rows.Add(new string[] { oPc.Company, oPc.FirstName, oPc.LastName, sUserName, Roles.GetRolesForUser(sUserName)[0] });
}
```

In the above code `oPi.UserName` correctly returns the username of each user but `GetUserProfile(sUserName)` always returns the profile of the currently logged in user.
When I display the Profile properties (FirstName, LastName etc.) on the page I see that these properties are for the currently logged in user in each row even though the UserName and roles of each users are displayed correctly in each row for the specified user. Please note that the username and the roles are not coming from the profile.

My UserProfile custom class is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Profile;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace WebAppName
{
    public class UserProfile : ProfileBase
    {
        public static UserProfile GetUserProfile(string username)
        {
            return Create(username) as UserProfile;
        }

        public static UserProfile GetUserProfile()
        {
            return Create(Membership.GetUser().UserName) as UserProfile;
        }

        [SettingsAllowAnonymous(true)]
        public string Company
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)HttpContext.Current.Profile.GetPropertyValue("Company");
            }
            set
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Profile.SetPropertyValue("Company", value);
            }
        }

        [SettingsAllowAnonymous(true)]
        public string FirstName
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)HttpContext.Current.Profile.GetPropertyValue("FirstName");
            }
            set
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Profile.SetPropertyValue("FirstName", value);
            }
        }

        [SettingsAllowAnonymous(true)]
        public string LastName
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)HttpContext.Current.Profile.GetPropertyValue("LastName");
            }
            set
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Profile.SetPropertyValue("LastName", value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My web.config file has following Profile section:

```
<profile inherits="WebAppName.UserProfile" enabled="true" defaultProvider="ProjectNameSqlProvider" automaticSaveEnabled="true">
    <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="ProjectNameSqlProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="MyConnectionString" applicationName="ProjectName" />
    </providers>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my own mistake. In my UserProfile class I am getting and setting the properties of current user; whereas, Jon Galloway in his article that I referred to in my original post is clearly getting/setting the properties of specified user - that is what I should have done. Thanks to those who may have tried to help.